# No operating System found in Vmware workstation 16 for Solaris 11 in MX Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, solaris

I have downloaded the Solaris 11 testing ISO from the official Solaris download page; I wanted to try out a Unix-based operating system. I have downloaded the ISO from [this link](https://www.oracle.com/solaris/solaris11/downloads/solaris11-install-downloads.html).

I have created a virtual machine for that ISO using Vmware Workstation 16.0.
However, I am not able to boot into the virtual environment.
The system is showing this error:

> No operating system found.

I am attaching a screenshot to give a better overview of what is happening.
[image]

I tried googling using this keyword: *" network boot from intel e1000 VMware operating system not found"* and got [this solution](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/vSphere-Upgrade-Install/Operating-system-not-found/td-p/912822).
After starting the virtual machine, I found that both *" connected"* and *" connect at power on"* options are enabled. Here is the image for convenience.

[image]

Thus I can conclude that this is not creating the issue.
So then, which is causing the machine to detect the ISO?

If anyone has experienced this before and knows about the workaround, please help me.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. The first thing that comes to my mind: is the ISO bootable? Please [edit] your post and add the download link (or page) for the ISO. Moreover it seems that the VM is booting from network and not from the ISO (CD): check the boot order.

Comment: If this is a all new environment (VMware and Solaris), have you enabled Hardware Virtualization in your host BIOS?

Comment: How to check the boot order? And this is not an all-new environment. I have installed several distros using VMware.

Comment: I have added the download link for the page. Please have a look at it.

Comment: I ran the command `file sol-11_4-text-sparc.iso` to test whether the ISO is bootable or not. And I got this output:
`sol-11_4-text-sparc.iso: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Oracle_Solaris-11_4-Text-SPARC'`  @Hastur

Comment: @ArkaBhuiyan Hi, are you emulating a RISC processor? Because from the name I guess you have downloaded an ISO for a RISC processor.  Try to download an x86 ISO... and let me know if it is for this reason.

Comment: A SPARC iso requires a SPARC CPU - VMware does not support SPARC - you need to use one of the x86 iso images instead.